# Force show vertical scroll bar on table

Tags: css, scrollbar

I am trying to force-show vertical scroll bar on my table. Here is my code:

```
<div style="height:95%;overflow:auto;">
   <table id="myTable" data-tableName="myContent" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; overflow:auto;">
      <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Please note that I have already tried `overflow: scroll`, `overflow-y: scroll` (with `!important`) along with a couple of other solutions but it doesn't work. I am using Chrome on Mac OS.

Comment: Firstly, Add height in pixels like this <div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some version of OSX hide scrollbars when not needed.
They probably hope to make the webpage slicker.
Try including this in your CSS file:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/UsvLN/)

[Source](http://simurai.com/blog/2011/07/26/webkit-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

You have used height in %. height can'be used in % if it is not in respect of something. So here you have to use height or max-height in pixels to work. Or if you want to make it percentage just make it absolute and its parent div relative so that it will take that percent of height with respect to its parent.

```html
<div style="max-height:100px;overflow-y:scroll ">
   <table id="myTable" data-tableName="myContent" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 1</td>
        <td>Content 2</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Height in percentage works like:-

```html
  <div style="height:200px;position:relative">
   <div style="height:50%;position:absolute;overflow-y:scroll ">
       <table id="myTable" data-tableName="myContent" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;">
          <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Content 1</td>
            <td>Content 2</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I ran your code snippet and it doesn't show vertical scroll bar in it all the time. It shows ONLY when I scroll and then it disappears. Is it something to do with Mac or Chrome on Mac?